# Add schema.org (JSON-LD) product objects to collection pages for an e-commerce website?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

Every e-commerce website has collection pages listing one or more products. I am trying to figure out the correct structured data to add to these collection pages. I have already added the CollectionPage object:

```
{
        "@context" : "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "CollectionPage",
        "name": "Shopify Apps",
        "url": "https://sherpas.design/pages/shopify-apps",
        "description": "We build apps that function and feel natively Shopify",
        "image": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0085/8515/0560/files/logox2_500x500.png?v=1555661781"
    }
```

But I am wondering whether I should add a product object for each product that appears on the collection page? Will this be semantically correct?

Answer (score 2):

This validates and conforms to Googles requirements that you should create a list that just contains URLs to the product pages. Adding the twist of using the CollectionPage may reduce the chances of getting rich results. I'd love confirmation that it works.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "CollectionPage",
  "name": "Shopify Apps",
  "url": "https://sherpas.design/pages/shopify-apps",
  "description": "We build apps that function and feel natively Shopify",
  "image": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0085/8515/0560/files/logox2_500x500.png?v=1555661781",
  "mainEntity" : {
    "@type":"ItemList",
    "itemListElement":[
      {
        "@type":"ListItem",
        "position":1,
        "url":"http://example.com/coffee_cake.html"
      },
      {
        "@type":"ListItem",
        "position":2,
        "url":"http://example.com/apple_pie.html"
      },
      {
        "@type":"ListItem",
        "position":3,
        "url":"http://example.com/blueberry-pie.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Adding the twist of using the CollectionPage may reduce the chances of getting rich results." Thanks!

Comment: The more you deviate from  what is stated in the guidelines, the bigger chance what you do is not supported by Google, even if it is technically correct.

Comment: Are you saying that it might be a good idea not to add the CollectionPage property at all?

Comment: I'd say that you won't get the carousel feature with products anyhow. I'd keep the CollectionPage